# Visual Studio 2013 not pointing out exceptions?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, exceptions

My VS has stopped telling me where my code errors are so I have no idea how to fix it when it crashes. What it used to do is something like this:

[image: Helpful exception dialog]

This exception dialog is very helpful. But it's gone for me. When I debug my program now, it just hangs then stops debugging. An extremely unhelpful error message appears in the Output too (nothing in the Error List though)

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in LidgrenTest.exe
The program '[6180] LidgrenTest.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

It doesn't even tell me what line it's on! Any ideas?

Comment: Quickest way would be to reinstall. Make a copy of the VS document folder, delete original. And create a new project and transfer just the code over.

Comment: First, note that the "A First change exception of type..." message is very common and does not always reflect an issue in your code (the exception may be occuring in an included library which handles it itself). I get them all the time in projects that are working perfectly fine. Second, note that since you show a try block with an empty catch, that exception should not break execution because it is handled (albeit badly).  Third, under Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, do you have the Exception Assistant enabled?

Comment: I apologise for the picture, it isn't my screenshot (as I cannot get the exception dialog to show up). I just found it on Google. And yes I do have the exception assistant enabled.

Comment: It looks like you need to change your exception settings in teh intellitrace window. first set up an exception of some kind, and run until it breaks there. then find the exception element in Intellitrace, and click Exception Settings inside the element. in there you will see a thousand checkboxes for every fricken type of exception there is. in the column titled "User Unhandled" make sure that the type of exception is checked, and it shoudl break on that line when the ex happens.

Comment: This is an issue I've been having as well, across several machines and re-installs...  I know in my case, the exception isn't handled anywhere in code.